# Graphing the derivative from a graphed function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, graphing-functions, solution-verification

> For the graphs of $f(x)$ make a sketch of the graph $f'(x)$

Here are the sketches I have so far. The graphs on the top row are the original functions. **Did I graph these correctly?**

[image]

Comment: Really nice job! (I wish my students always did so well.) A couple of minor remarks. On the first graph, the slope definitely becomes greater than $2$ just to the left of $x=0$. (The line you drew for negative $x$-values should be steeper.) On the middle one, the slope reaches a relative minimum a bit to the left of $x=2$ (and the minimum looks to be about $-2$, not $-1$). These are pretty minor complaints, though!

Comment: @SteveKass Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind what Steve said in his comment, your graphs are exactly right!

For reference, the comment by Steve:

> Really nice job! (I wish my students always did so well.) A couple of minor remarks. On the first graph, the slope definitely becomes greater than $2$ just to the left of $x=0$. (The line you drew for negative $x$-values should be steeper.) On the middle one, the slope reaches a relative minimum a bit to the left of $x=2$ (and the minimum looks to be about $-2$, not $-1$). These are pretty minor complaints, though!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1157711)

Comment: @AlanMuniz The question was answered in the comments, so without an actual answer, it will sit in the "unanswered" queue for the rest of time. See [this Meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4423/unanswered-questions) and [this one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments) for more discussion of questions that have been answered in comments. Moreover, the question is, essentially, "Is this correct?", and since the graphs are indeed correct, what more could be put in an answer besides some variation on "yes?"